# Android makefile error: recipe commences before first target

Tags: android, makefile

During build I get this error

> Android.mk:145: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

My compiler should be a gcc from an android toolchain.

This is the interesting recipe

```
ifneq ($(MTK_TEE_SUPPORT),yes)
trustzone:
else
ifeq ($(MTK_IN_HOUSE_TEE_SUPPORT),yes)
# export for build.sh
#include $(MTK_PATH_CUSTOM)/trustzone/custom.mk
#export TEE_DRAM_SIZE:=$(MEMSIZE)
#export MTEE_CUSTOM_CFG_DIR:=$(MTK_PATH_CUSTOM)/trustzone
export HOST_OS
TRUST_TEE_IMAGES := $(OUT_DIR)/target/product/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/trustzone/bin/tz.img
trustzone: 
else # for TRUSTONIC_TEE_SUPPORT
trustzone: mcDriverDaemon
endif
endif
ifeq ($(TRUSTZONE_PARTITION),yes)
  ifneq ($(wildcard $(TRUST_TEE_WD)/build.sh),)
    $(hide) echo $(SHOWTIME) $@ ing ...            //this is line 145
    $(hide) echo -e \\t\\t\\t\\b\\b\\b\\bLOG: $(LOG_DIR)$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)_$@.log
    $(hide) rm -f $(LOG_DIR)$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)_$@.log $(LOG_DIR)$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)_$@.log_err
    $(hide) $(SHELL) $(TZ_BUILD_SCRIPT) $(MTK_PROJECT_NAME) $(DEAL_STDOUT)
    $(hide) cp -f $(TRUST_TEE_IMAGES) $(LOG_DIR)/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/
    $(hide) mkdir -p $(LOG_DIR)/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/system/etc/
    $(hide) cp -f $(TRUST_TEE_IMAGES) $(LOG_DIR)/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/system/etc/trustzone.bin
  else
    $(hide) echo Not find $(TRUST_TEE_WD)/build.sh, skip $@.
  endif
else
    $(hide) echo Not support $@.
endif

droidcore: trustzone

endif
```

Comment: Likely, a condition statement that is above the line `trustzone:` is wrong. Which line is #145? the line which starts with `$(hide) echo $(SHOWTIME)`?

Comment: I edited the question adding earlier lines of makefile. Line 145 is the one I'va already marked with a comment. Obviously that comment is not present in real code.

Comment: I add another detail: the spaces before every $(hide) statement are tabs, I tried to substitute with simple spaces, and at that point the error changed in 
_target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop._
Indeed, those commands seems to me to not belong to any rule.

Comment: I would add `$(info ...)` statements to figure out what parts of the makefile are being used and what parts are not.  Also it would be helpful if you specified which version of GNU make you're using.

Comment: I was sure I had already wrote that gcc is at version 4.9. I was wrong. Where would you put the info statements?

Comment: I said "GNU make", not "GCC".  Doesn't matter what version of GCC you're using if the problem is your makefile.  I would put them in each of the different parts of the ifeq/else/etc. so you can follow the logic of which path is taken, by which different info output is printed, so you know which one is supposed to be defining the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was Gnu Make version. At [this official page](https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html#packages)
it's clearly stated that Android build system reference make versions are 3.81-3.82. I installed one of these previous versions and now that makefile doesn't give any error, without need of any patch.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in GNU make.  It's closing that rule off before it should due to the ifeq/endif.  For this specific example you could rewrite it more simply like this:

```
PREREQ =

ifeq ($(MTK_TEE_SUPPORT),yes)
 ifeq ($(MTK_IN_HOUSE_TEE_SUPPORT),yes)
# export for build.sh
#include $(MTK_PATH_CUSTOM)/trustzone/custom.mk
#export TEE_DRAM_SIZE:=$(MEMSIZE)
#export MTEE_CUSTOM_CFG_DIR:=$(MTK_PATH_CUSTOM)/trustzone
export HOST_OS
TRUST_TEE_IMAGES := $(OUT_DIR)/target/product/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/trustzone/bin/tz.img

 else # for TRUSTONIC_TEE_SUPPORT
PREREQ = mcDriverDaemon
 endif
endif
trustzone: $(PREREQ)
ifeq ($(TRUSTZONE_PARTITION),yes)
  ifneq ($(wildcard $(TRUST_TEE_WD)/build.sh),)
        $(hide) echo $(SHOWTIME) $@ ing ...            //this is line 145
        $(hide) echo -e \\t\\t\\t\\b\\b\\b\\bLOG: $(LOG_DIR)$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)_$@.log
        $(hide) rm -f $(LOG_DIR)$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)_$@.log $(LOG_DIR)$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)_$@.log_err
        $(hide) $(SHELL) $(TZ_BUILD_SCRIPT) $(MTK_PROJECT_NAME) $(DEAL_STDOUT)
        $(hide) cp -f $(TRUST_TEE_IMAGES) $(LOG_DIR)/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/
        $(hide) mkdir -p $(LOG_DIR)/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/system/etc/
        $(hide) cp -f $(TRUST_TEE_IMAGES) $(LOG_DIR)/$(MTK_PROJECT_NAME)/system/etc/trustzone.bin
  else
        $(hide) echo Not find $(TRUST_TEE_WD)/build.sh, skip $@.
  endif
else
        $(hide) echo Not support $@.
endif
```

However please report a bug on this in the Savannah bug tracker: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make

Here's a minimal reproduce case:

```
ifneq ($(FOO),yes)
foobar:
else
BAR = bar
foobar:
endif
        @echo one
```

If you run:

```
$ make
Makefile:7: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

$ make FOO=yes
one
```

Apparently the variable assignment in the `else` is breaking things when the `else` path is not taken.

Comment: In this way, this variable assignment `PREREQ = mcDriverDaemon` shouldn't fall in the same case?

Comment: No, because the target `trustzone` is only defined one time, _outside_ the `ifeq`, rather than being defined multiple times inside each leg of the `ifeq`.

Comment: With your changes I get _Android.mk:146: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop._
My version of make is Gnu Make 4.1

Comment: Make thinks that line 146 is a new rule, not part of the recipe for the previous rule.  Make sure that the first character on that line is a literal TAB character.

Comment: Thanks MadScientist. Your solution worked, but I preferred to solve the problem at root downgrading my make version. Do you think that this should be reported to bugtracker, or that it could be an expected behaviour of newer version of Gnu Make?

Comment: I already said, above, that it was a bug and should be reported.

Comment: @MadScientist is the main developer of GNU make (and has been so since 1997 or so), so his opinion is more dispositive than most.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to report this!